# iOS settings bundle: How to validate input

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, settings, nsuserdefaults

I would like to store numeric values in the iOS settings bundle. However, I did not find a way to restrict the valid range for these values.

Is it possible to enter a minimum and maximum range or check the range in code?

When using a slider, it is possible to limit the range by setting the minimum and maximum value. However, the actual value selected by the user is not shown. Is it possible to show the actual value in addition to the slider?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `showValue` key to `<true />` for the slider cell to show its value, as described [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences_specifier_plist#Slider_and_switch_cells).

Comment: I have set `<key>showValue</key>`to `<true />`. However, I don't get the value displayed. Did I miss something? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexR Most certainly, but I don't know what in the complete lack of information.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. The Apple docs don't list is as an option: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/preferencesettings/conceptual/settingsapplicationschemareference/Articles/PSSliderSpecifier.html

Comment: @MathewS It's not documented, since this is an... khm... **undocumented** feature. It may have changed with the frameworks over time.